# Unable to make a bridge between two classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, web-scraping

I've written some code in python and my intention is to supply the newly produced links by "web_parser" class to the "get_docs" class. However, I can't think of anything productive to do so. All I wanna do is bridge a connection between the two classes so that the "web_parser" class produce links and the "get_docs" class process them to get the refined output. Any idea as to how I can do it flawlessly will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

class web_parser:

    page_link = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=pizza&geo_location_terms=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA"
    main_url = "https://www.yellowpages.com"

    def __init__(self, link):

        self.link = link
        self.vault = []

    def parser(self):
        self.get_link(self.page_link)

    def get_link(self, url):

        page = requests.get(url)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
        item_links = tree.xpath('//h2[@class="n"]/a[@class="business-name"][not(@itemprop="name")]/@href')
        for item_link in item_links:
            self.vault.append(self.main_url + item_link)


class get_docs(web_parser):

    def __init__(self, new_links):
        web_parser.__init__(self, link)
        self.new_links = [new_links]

    def procuring_links(self):
        for link in self.vault:
            self.using_links(link)


    def using_links(self, newly_created_link):

        page = requests.get(newly_created_link)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
        name = tree.findtext('.//div[@class="sales-info"]/h1')
        phone = tree.findtext('.//p[@class="phone"]')
        print(name, phone)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    crawl = web_parser(web_parser.page_link)
    parse = get_docs(crawl)
    parse.parser()
    parse.procuring_links()
```

I know a very little about creating classes so please forgive my ignorance. Upon execution at this stage I get an error:

```
    web_parser.__init__(self, link)
NameError: name 'link' is not defined
```

Comment: Did you try storing the data in a container defined in the outer scope of the two classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very sure how you want to use it, by giving a parameter to web_parser or use an hardcoded link inside the class ?

From the commands you are using in `__main__`, you could process like below:

```
class get_docs(object):

    def __init__(self, web_parser):
        self.vault = web_parser.vault


if __name__ == '__main__':

    crawl = web_parser() # create an instance
    crawl.parser()
    parse = get_docs(crawl)  # give the instance to get_doc, or directly the vault with crawl.vault
    parse.procuring_links()  # execute get_doc processing
```

__

You'll need to correct the web_parser class too:

you have to choose between a parameter given during creation (`link`), or the hardcoded page_link, just adapt the method `parser()` to target the good one.

```
class web_parser:

    def __init__(self, link=''):

        self.link = link
        self.vault = []
        self.page_link = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=pizza&geo_location_terms=San%20Francisco%2C%20CA"
        self.main_url = "https://www.yellowpages.com"
```

Comment: Thanks PRMoureu for your answer. As soon as I am near my pc i will test it and let you know the feedback. Thanks again.

Comment: @SMth80 no prob, now i know the name of pizzeria in San Francisco

Comment: Dear  PRMoureu, I tested your code and got it working. Just a little explanation on how this "self.vault = web_parser.vault" is done would be very helpful for me. So far i knew "self.vault = web_parser" is the right approach. Again, forgive my ignorance. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SMth80 it's depending on what parameter you give to `parse =  get_docs(crawl)`, this is actually the bridge you were looking for : you tell the 2nd class what you need from the 1st. As we only need the vault, we grab it directly, if we were using the web_parser too, it would be easier to keep `self.webparser = web_parser` and call the vault when needed, with `self.webparser.vault`

Comment: In the comments i say you could even give directly `parse = get_docs(crawl.vault)`, then the code will be `self.vault = parser_vault` (don't forget to change the parameter in the constructor: `def __init__(self, parser_vault)`)

Comment: Thanks for everything, PRMoureu.

Comment: Hey PRMoureu, you might want to follow the link: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264193/trouble-running-my-class-crawler" Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the NameError you posted in your question, you need to add another parameter to `__init__` of your subclass - and pass something to it.

```
class get_docs(web_parser):

    #def __init__(self, new_links):
    def __init__(self, link, new_links):
        web_parser.__init__(self, link)
        self.new_links = [new_links]
```

Although `web_parser` doesn't seem to do anything with that data so maybe just remove it from the base class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer wwii. It works fine as well. I would have accepted your answer if i got you first. Thanks again.