# Trouble running my class crawler

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, web-scraping

Writing a class crawler in python, I got stuck on the half-way. I can't find any idea how to pass the newly produced links [generated by app_crawler class] to the "App" class so that I can do the rest over there. If anyone points me into the right direction by showing how can I run it, I would be very helpful. Thanks in advance. Btw, it is also running but only for a single link.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

class app_crawler:

    starturl = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/candy-crush-saga/id553834731?mt=8"

    def crawler(self):
        self.get_app(self.starturl)


    def get_app(self, link):
        page = requests.get(link)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
        links = tree.xpath('//div[@class="lockup-info"]//*/a[@class="name"]/@href')
        for link in links:
            return link # I wish to make this link penetrate through the App class but can't get any idea


class App(app_crawler):

    def __init__(self, link):
        self.links = [link]

    def process_links(self):
        for link in self.links:
            self.get_item(link)

    def get_item(self, url):
        page = requests.get(url)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
        name = tree.xpath('//h1[@itemprop="name"]/text()')[0]
        developer = tree.xpath('//div[@class="left"]/h2/text()')[0]        
        price = tree.xpath('//div[@itemprop="price"]/text()')[0]
        print(name, developer, price)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parse = App(app_crawler.starturl)
    parse.crawler()
    parse.process_links()
```

I've created another one which is working fine but I wanted to make the above crawler to get a different look. Here is the link for the working one:
"https://www.dropbox.com/s/galjorcdynueequ/Working%20one.txt?dl=0"

Comment: [Edit] your Question and and explain `parse = App(crawl)`, why do you Initialize `App(...)` with a Class Instance instead of the _**starturl**_ as defined in ` def __init__(self, starturl='', links=''):`

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code:

- `App` inherits from `app_crawler` yet you provide an `app_crawler` instance to `App.__init__`.
- `App.__init__` calls `app_crawler.__init__` instead of `super().__init__()`.
- Not only `app_crawler.get_app` doesn't actually return *anything*, it creates a brand new `App` object.

This results in your code passing an `app_crawler` object to `requests.get` instead of a url string.

You have *too much* encapsulation in your code.

Consider the following code that is shorter than your not-working code, cleaner and without needing to needlessly pass objects around:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

class App:
    def __init__(self, starturl):
        self.starturl = starturl
        self.links = []

    def get_links(self):
        page = requests.get(self.starturl)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
        self.links = tree.xpath('//div[@class="lockup-info"]//*/a[@class="name"]/@href')

    def process_links(self):
        for link in self.links:
            self.get_docs(link)

    def get_docs(self, url):
        page = requests.get(url)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
        name = tree.xpath('//h1[@itemprop="name"]/text()')[0]
        developper = tree.xpath('//div[@class="left"]/h2/text()')[0]
        price = tree.xpath('//div[@itemprop="price"]/text()')[0]
        print(name, developper, price)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse = App("https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/candy-crush-saga/id553834731?mt=8")
    parse.get_links()
    parse.process_links()
```

outputs

```
Cookie Jam By Jam City, Inc. Free
Zombie Tsunami By Mobigame Free
Flow Free By Big Duck Games LLC Free
Bejeweled Blitz By PopCap Free
Juice Jam By Jam City, Inc. Free
Candy Crush Soda Saga By King Free
Bubble Witch 3 Saga By King Free
Candy Crush Jelly Saga By King Free
Farm Heroes Saga By King Free
Pet Rescue Saga By King Free
```

Comment: Thanks sir DeepSpace, for your answer. Basically, it's not my intention how easily I can get the results, rather, how I could supply the links to the "App" class which are generated by "app_crawler" class so that I can process things in my "App" class as though it's a bridge. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I was expecting my code should be:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

class app_crawler:

    starturl = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/candy-crush-saga/id553834731?mt=8"

    def __init__(self):
        self.links = [self.starturl]


    def crawler(self):
        for link in self.links:
            self.get_app(link)


    def get_app(self, link):
        page = requests.get(link)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
        links = tree.xpath('//div[@class="lockup-info"]//*/a[@class="name"]/@href')
        for link in links:
            if not len(self.links)>=5:
                self.links.append(link)


class App(app_crawler):

    def __init__(self):
        app_crawler.__init__(self)


    def process_links(self):
        for link in self.links:
            self.get_item(link)

    def get_item(self, url):
        page = requests.get(url)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
        name = tree.xpath('//h1[@itemprop="name"]/text()')[0]
        developer = tree.xpath('//div[@class="left"]/h2/text()')[0]        
        price = tree.xpath('//div[@itemprop="price"]/text()')[0]
        print(name, developer, price)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    scrape = App()
    scrape.crawler()
    scrape.process_links()
```